# Sending custom object through Netty dynamically

Tags: netty, nio, asyncsocket

I have created a PoC in Netty to send and receive java objects. I am sending the object, which I created when the clientHandler initializes. How do I send a object which I creates on run time or how do I wrte a send method which send my object to the Netty server?.

I just copied my client handler code. Here I creates the player object in the constructor. In case I created the player object after the clientHandler object created, How do I send this object?.

public class ObjectEchoClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

```
private Player player;

/**
 * Creates a client-side handler.
 */
public ObjectEchoClientHandler() {

    player =  new Player("Neymer","Brazil",10);

}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    // Send the first message if this handler is a client-side handler.
    ctx.writeAndFlush(player);
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    // Echo back the received object to the server.
    ctx.write(msg);
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.flush();
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Bibin

Answer (score 1):

You would just use Channel.writeAndFlush(yourObject) ?